# Jquery select href to JPG

Tags: jquery, html

I need to select with jQuery `<a href="">` , but only 'href' with extensions '.JPG' or '.jpg'

For example :

To find only this 'links'

```
<a target="_blank" href="images/test.jpg" class="highslide ">
   <img src="images/test.jpg" alt='img'/>
</a>

<a target="_blank" href="images/test.JPG" class="highslide ">
   <img src="images/test.JPG" alt='img'/>
</a>
```

but not this

```
<a target="_blank" href="galery.html" class="highslide ">
   <img src="images/test.JPG" alt='img'/>
</a>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
$("a[href$=.jpg], a[href$=.JPG]")...
```

Answer (score 2):

```
$("a[href$='.jpg']")
```

See [Selectors/attributeEndsWith](http://docs.jquery.com/Selectors/attributeEndsWith#attributevalue) in the jQuery documentation.